# TypeORM ReferenceError: X is not defined

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I'm setting up my database tables using TypeORM. I have a `User` entity and a `MediaList` entity. The `User` has a OneToMany relationship with the `MediaList` entity as follows:

```
@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') public id: string;

  @Column('varchar', {length: 50, name: 'first_name'})
  public firstName: string;

  @Column('varchar', {length: 50, name: 'last_name'})
  public lastName: string;

  @Column('varchar', {nullable: false, length: 255})
  public email: string;
  .
  .
  .
  @OneToMany((type) => MediaList, (mediaList) => mediaList.owner)
  public mediaLists: MediaList[];
}

@Entity('media_list')
export class MediaList extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') public id: string;

  @Column('varchar', {length: 50})
  public title: string;

  @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.mediaLists)
  public owner: User;
}
```

I create a user as such:

```
    const user = User.create({
        firstName: 'john',
        lastName: 'doe',
        email,
        password,
        permissions: generalPermissions,
    });

    await user.save();
```

When I save the user, I get a reference error:

```
(node:16708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: MediaList is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here? Are my mappings incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is basically with ESM, because circular references give null values.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2059

Answer (score 0):

For anyone counter problem like

`ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)`
or

`'ReferenceError: Entity is not defined'`

it's probably you didn't specify entity in typeormconfig

```
export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  username: "admin",
  password: "admin",
  database: "yourdatabase",
  entities: [your entities], //Dont use [__dirname + "/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
  synchronize: true,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I try to establish relations with my existing tables in database. What is weird I don't have this issue with rest tables only with specific three tables which has relations.

> ReferenceError: MySomeEntity is not defined

I didn't have time to investigate where exactly was a problem, but definitely it has to be investigated and reported to developer.

I just solved this by removing all @OneToMany/@ManyToOne decorators and use leftJoinAndMapMany/leftJoinAndMapOne instead leftJoinAndSelect when I need to link my relations in a query.

It works.